# Mapping Entity and Inherit from a Entity Framework's Entity with new the parent's properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop

I'm using Entity Framework. My .net Framework is 3.5 and i can't improve it because of company's policy.my model is database-first and i have an entity called `RequestMaster`. I don't want to use it directly then I've created a derived class of each entity that inherits it

Now Suppose my RequestMaster is :

```
public class RequestMaster
    {
        public int RequestId{ get; set; }

        public RequestType RequestType { get; set; }
    }
```

and the derived class is :

```
public class Request : RequestMaster
{

    public List<Request> SelectAll()
    {

        return _dataContext.RequestMaster
                        .Include("RequestType")
                        .Select(x => new Request()
                        {

                            RequestId = x.RequestId,
                            RequestType = x.RequestType,


                        }).ToList();
    }

}
```

then I use it :

```
 var req = new Request ();
 _request = req.SelectAll();
```

My problem is all properties( RequestId and RequestType) are zero or null, i've checked and see everything is okay but problem is in the mapping RequestMaster to Request. i changed the Request and override the RequestMaster's properties and the problem solved!

```
 public class Request : RequestMaster
    {


        public new int  RequestId { get; set; }
        public new int RequestType { get; set; }

        public void SelectAll()
        {

            return _dataContext.RequestMaster
                            .Include("RequestType")
                            .Select(x => new Request()
                            {

                                RequestId = x.RequestId,
                                RequestType = x.RequestType,


                            }).ToList();
        }

    }
```

Could anybody tell me what's wrong with my mapping and how the new property solved it?

Comment: why does your `SelectAll` method has a return type of `void`?

Comment: shouldn't your method SelectAll have a return type? instead of void?

Comment: sorry, it's return type is List<Request> , my mistake to change it in the question. i edited the question.

Comment: I'm almost definite you don't need the select at all, unless I'm missing something. You can simply write: `return _dataContext.RequestMaster.Include("RequestType").ToList();`. I don't have an answer of why your code doesn't work, but it's usually not advised to create entities manually when querying via EF (there's not really a point) - better to return a viewmodel, or another object unrelated to the database instead.

Comment: Why do you need `Request` to inherit from `RequestMaster`? Can't you use composition instead?

Comment: But that would return `RequestMaster`s and not `Request`s

Comment: @singsuyash Well, yes, but if you're querying `RequestMaster` you probably don't want to force it into a `Request`.

Comment: SelectAll  it's not the only method of the Request, it's going to do more, the code has been simplified , i'm going to make a repository for my actual entities, i'm new in design pattern and it's started ,like that, but it will be improve and complete. so for now i just want to not use the context directly. in my form

Comment: @samirariazati So I think you will find my answer helpful:)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need inheritance:

- To shape the result to `Request` , you even don't need inheritance, just shape it.
- To add a method to `RequestMaster`, you don't need inheritance, just crate another file and create a `public partial class RequestMaster` and add your method `public List<RequestMaster> SelectAll()` or `public List<Request> SelectAll()` to it.
- To drive a class from your base entity and have mapping still work, you should use standard mechanism of inheritance in EF like [`Table Per Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716702(v=vs.90).aspx) for example.

But in general I strongly recommend to not do that and instead, separate concerns and use a different class called for example `RequestMasterBusinessLogic` to contain that logic, 
you can also shape your entities here in this class and if you really need a Request class too, write this code in `RequestMasterBusinessLogic` without deriving from `RequestMaster`:

```
public partial class RequestMasterBusinessLogic
{
    private YourDataContext Context;
    public RequestMasterBusinessLogic()
    {
        Context= new YourDataContext();
    }
    public List<RequestMaster> SelectAll()
    {
         Context.RequestMaster.Include("RequestType").ToList();
    }
    public List<Request> SelectAllRequests()
    {
         Context.RequestMaster
                .Include("RequestType")
                .Select(x => new Request()
                {
                    RequestId = x.RequestId,
                    RequestType = x.RequestType,
                }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, it's helpful and i'll use it, thanks,  but could you tell me what's wrong with my mapping? an why it's work with new properties?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @samirariazati, to be honest I'm not sure about the reason of working the solution when you used `new` but I know when you need to use inheritance with EF you should also edit mappings. I'll notify you If I had a better answer for your comment :)